# How to correctly use ResultSet class in JDBC for my situation?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm adding customers to a database but only if there is no other CustomerID in the database that is the same as the CustomerID I just entered.  I'm using JDBC and MySQL to do this in Eclipse.  Can someone tell me if my while loop is set up correctly to achieve this?  I've been getting a lot of weird output so it probably isn't.  I've been looking around online for hours now but I can't get this to work.  How can I do this correctly?  A piece  of my code is shown below.

```
public void addCust() {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/northwind?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=EST";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "<password>";
    String tempCustID, custID, comp, contName, contTitle, addr, city, reg, postCode, country, phone, fax;

    System.out.println("Loading driver...");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded!");
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e);
    }

    System.out.println("Connecting database...");

    try {
        Connection mycon = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        System.out.println("Database connected!");

        Scanner keyboard1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter 5 letters to identify the customer as.");
        tempCustID = keyboard1.nextLine();
        custID = tempCustID.toUpperCase();
        /**
        if(custID == "") {
            System.out.println("Must enter a value.");
            addCust();
        }
        */

        PreparedStatement stat = mycon.prepareStatement("SELECT CustomerID FROM customers");
        ResultSet cust = stat.executeQuery();
        while(cust.next()) {
            String customerID = cust.getString("CustomerID");
            if(custID == customerID) {
                System.out.println("Customer ID already exists. Please enter a different sequence of 5 letters to identify the customer as.");
                options();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does "I can't get this to work" mean?

Comment: Please provide what is happening exactly.

Comment: Got it working with equals method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use equals method to compare string instead of "=="

Comment: Thank you! Been a while since I've written in Java but the equals method rings a bell.